# English analogy for why 我是去...的 can't appear without context

Tags: grammar

I understand 我是上个星期去法国吃的美食 means something like "I went to France last week to eat good food"

But why can 我是去...的 phrases like 我是上个星期去法国吃的美食 only be answers to questions (or otherwise attached to a larger grammatical context)?

I can't think of a way to express all the meanings of 我是上个星期去法国吃的美食 in English in a way that is also only a sentence fragment (the type of construction in English that would be valid as an answer to a question but not by itself) and not a valid sentence itself.

Is there any analogue to 我是去...的 phrases in English? Why can't they actually stand alone?

Comment: Why is it not valid stand-alone? Any source? Do you think the English it-cleft sentence can stand alone? They’re thought to be more or less equivalent. (here the Chinese structure is actually pseudo-cleft not cleft per se)

Comment: @lilysirius My Chinese friends don't think it can exist in isolation. I don't think the English cleft sentence can stand alone. And [looking at the Wikipedia page for cleft sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence#Mandarin), I think "it's equivalent to a cleft sentence" is a perfect answer, I didn't know this before.

Comment: Just to be clear, what's your definition of stand-alone, being able to form an independent clause or being able to stand without any context? I think the former doesn't have controversy, while some might frowns on the latter and feel it's incomplete. I reckon its incompleteness but don't think it's a syntactical issue. The "incompleteness" can be filled by a contrastive clause either before or after it. Or discourse-wise it implies more independent sentences to come.

Comment: A man walks into the reception area of a company: M: 你好！W: 你好！M: 我是来面试的。W: 好的先生，请在这里登记一下。Not 我是去 。。。的 but 我是来 。。。的 The receptionist could have said 你是来干嘛。 but that would not be very polite. So no question was asked. Don't know if that helps, I just got that from a friend.

Comment: @Pedroski because of the situation (entering a reception), perhaps there is an implied question from the woman to the man: Who are you? (What entity are you representing during this visit to our company? What is your purpose of coming here? How can I help you?) Maybe because it is an introduction situation, that's what makes this construction possible in this situation. Good example though, proves it doesn't have to be a response to a direct question.

Comment: @lilysirius would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in earlier comments, this structure is similar to the English it-cleft sentence. They’re thought to be more or less equivalent. (here the Chinese structure is actually pseudo-cleft not cleft per se).

> Does it form an independent clause?

Yes. It is completely both syntactically and semantically.

> Can it stand without any context?

Well, discourse-wise, it is somewhat incomplete. Compare 我上个星期去法国吃美食了, which is discourse-wise complete, that is it does not need prior contexts or strongly suggest more sentences to come.

As for 我是上个星期去法国吃的美食, it does not need to be an answer to a question. For native speakers, it is actually usually not an answer to a question; it sounds weird. In the answer, unnecessary information is omitted.

> 你是什么时候去法国吃的美食？
>
> 上个星期。/我（是）上个星期去的。

The discourse "incompleteness" instead comes from its rather strong suggestion of more sentences to come. It can be filled by a contrastive clause after it. For example,

> 我是上个星期去法国吃的美食。他是上个月去的。

Or, we can just more details about the trip.

> 我是上个星期去法国吃的美食。正好赶上圣诞节，我在圣诞集市里尝试了许多不同的传统小吃。

---

Why does 我是上个星期去法国吃的美食 suggests more sentences to come while 我上个星期去法国吃美食了 does not?

The latter is an unmarked statement of a past action. However, the former has a focus on 上个星期. Logically there should be some reason for the focus. From the sentence alone we don't see it. Thus the listener or reader would wait for upcoming sentences to resolve it. But this does not invalidate its status as an independent clause. The issue is at the discourse level.

Similarly,

> 总分结构总体来说就是表示总叙和分述的关系的结构方式。

is syntactically and semantically complete, yet still invites more sentences to come. 总体来说 is generally speaking, readers would naturally wait to see some specific statements or examples.

Answer (score 1):

One fragmental English sentence coming up:

Where'd you go last weekend?
上周末你去哪儿了？
France, get some good grub.
我在法国吃了很美味的食物。

Comment: Isn't 我在法国吃了很美味的食物 is a totally grammatical standalone sentence in Chinese? I can walk up to a friend and say: 好久不见！我在法国吃了很美味的食物。  (It also doesn't use the 是去...的 structure I'm really most interested in)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted a fragment sentence in English! Always in a hurry! I think your assumption " Why can't they actually stand alone? only be answers to questions?" is not correct: Not an answer to a question, but a question: 1. 我是去面试还是去进行非正式的谈话？But, of course, no language is an island, it always occurs in a context!

Comment: You're right, I guess they can't only be answers to questions. But they do seem to be only sentence fragments, and never stand alone. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

How about the translations below:

- 我是上个星期去法国吃的美食 - It was last week I went to France to taste its delicious food.
- It was last month I flew to the US to start studying law - 我是上个月飛去美國去開始讀法律.

Note that direct one-to-one translation rarely works between Chinese and English due to differences in grammar. And, this type of sentence is usually a collective response to questions involving "when", "where", and "why/what you did".

Answer (score 1):

我是上个星期去法国吃的美食
it lays stress on the time as "上个星期"
我是去法国吃的美食
it lays stress on the aim place as "法国"

Answer (score 0):

> 我是上个星期去法国吃的美食

It could mean

> "I was the good food that went to France to eat last week"

It is inadvisable.

[我是 ~~ 的] here  should not be followed by an object, that makes 的 an adjective marker

的 in [我是 ~~ 的] here is a structure that encloses a statement to confirm or affirm it

Example

- 我去中國讀書 = I went to China to study
- [**我是**][去中國讀書][**的**] = [**I was**] [going to China to study]
- 我不會同意 = I am not going to agree
- [**我是**][不會同意][**的**] = [**I am**][not going to agree]

~

when 的 in [是 ~~ 的] is an adjective marker, it has to be followed by an object

Example

[這是公司的][車] = [this is] [company's] [car]

You can omit [車] if it is an answer and the question already included it as an object

Example

Q: 這車是誰的?

A: (*這車*)是公司的

Q: 這是誰的車?

A: (*這*)是公司的(*車*)

Comment: 你什么时候去法国吃了美食？ 我是上个星期去法国吃的美食  — I thought this was grammatical?

Comment: 我是上个星期去法国吃的 or 我是上个星期去法国吃美食的 is  grammatical

Comment: I've seen some examples with an object after 的, e.g. 我是上个星期去看的这场电影. Is this technically ungrammatical? Just part of slang or something?

Comment: 1. (SVO) "我是上个星期去看这场电影的"  2. (Topic + comment) "这场电影我是上个星期去看的" 3. (mix up of SVO and topic +comment) 我是上个星期去看的这场电影. (I say it is mixed up because otherwise, it would be an SVO sentence meaning " I am the movies that last week went to see"

Comment: Is it ungrammatical or otherwise illicit to mix up the structures like that?

Comment: Ok. It is inadvisable"  because you can read it either way. It sounds more like " I am the movies that last week went to see"

Comment: Maybe 我是上个星期去法国吃美食的 is a more acceptable construction. My original question would still be the same: Why can that only be the answer to a question? Why isn't it grammatical as a standalone sentence?

Comment: if [我是 ~~ 的 + objece] is an answer, the object can be omitted because it was mentioned in the question. When answering "這車是誰的?" you don't have to repeat the object and answer "這車是公司的". Simply replying "是公司的" is enough, we all understand what the object is.  If you have no object in a stand-alone sentence, the sentence wouldn't be a completed one, "是公司的" --> (是公司的 what?)